# How to convert Unicode to UTF8 in BB10 cascades

Tags: unicode, utf-8, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am working with TCP socket which I receive **unicode** data data for every 1 sec, data includes **arabic** text.

That unicode data I need to convert it to **UTF8** and pass to **JSON**

How to convert unicode to UTF8 in blackberry 10 qt cascades.?

I am using the following code to convert but it is **not working**.

```
QString appTitle = QString::fromLocal8Bit(data2.toAscii());
```

I receive data in this format.

[image]

Comment: "Unicode" is not a concrete encoding. What does the data look like exactly?

Comment: I have added an image. How I receive data. Please have a look.

Comment: OK, yes, you're receiving Arabic text, in JSON, *possibly* UTF-8 encoded (but one can't tell from just a screenshot). What's your question again?

Comment: UTF-8 is one of several Unicode representations. You can convert from one representation to another if you know the representation of the input. It's likely that the input is *already* encoded as UTF-8.